# Flutter app initialization at Onboard Pages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-navigation, flutter-packages

I want to take user input after user install and launch the app. I want set parameters like language Selection, date etc when he use app for first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SharedPreferences`

Have a page to take user inputs about your desired parameteres and ssave them in whereever you want to. While saving that, also store a `boolean` in `SharedPref` to indicate whether app is initialized or not.

In `main()` first you read this value from `SharedPref`. If the value is present then directly show your app's homepage else show the user input page.

This is similar to apps which have a login screen. In apps the login screen will appear only for the first time till user presses logout.

Check this package: [SharedPreference](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)